# Making .log files persistent

Tags: python, file, logging, persistent-storage, python-watchdog

I have a software which generates .log files, and the problem is that they are not persistent (each time the programs try to write an event it might rewrite over an past event which is not desirable)

Do you know a way in which I can write a python script for detecting when the program is opening a .log file in order to write something and make sure that he is not overwriting?

Thanks!

Comment: Can the program not just append rather than overwrite?

Comment: I don't have access to the program sourcecode

Answer (score 1):

you can use module logger, this is specialy for create logs, logs may be ephemeral usefull if you have serveless technology, if you want persist logs you can make:

```
import logging 
import logging.config 
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) 
logging.config.fileConfig('mylog.log', disable_existing_loggers=False)
logger.info('It works!')
```

Now you can see a filename named lo mylog.log

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the `logging` package defaults to append

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
            filename=<out-path>, # to print stdout to file
            format=line_format,
            level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Then, you can write to the logfile by

```
logging.info(.)
```

or another one of [`logging`'s levels](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open the log file in write mode.
You Have To Open The File In Append Mode 
Try

```
f=open('<filename>','a')
f.write(<log entry>)
f.close()
```